# Global Assembly Cache error when trying to install ClickOnce application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

In the past I was able to successfully build and install my application without any issues. I started getting this error in my compile window:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3340,5): warning MSB3187: Referenced assembly 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap\v4.0_11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll' targets a different processor than the application.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3340,5): warning MSB3187: Referenced assembly 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.SqlServer.Msxml6_interop\v4.0_11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Msxml6_interop.dll' targets a different processor than the application.
```

After looking some stuff up it was suggested that I try to change my application properties. I went to the build tab and targeted a specific CPU (x86). In the past I had it set to "Any CPU" and it always worked fine. Now when I try to install my application, I get the following error:

[image: ALT text - A busy cat]

I have been researching for two days now. I've found a few similar issues, but nothing like this one. Has anyone dealt with this issue before? I'm very open to suggestions at this juncture.

Ironically, we don't even use Microsoft SQL Server. I don't have it installed.

Comment: Are there any references to SQLServer in your Project, either in References or in using-directives?

Comment: @fk2 I have no references to SQLServer.  I have a reference to OTA COM so I can access a Sybase DB.  -- That's another reason why I'm so confused.

Comment: The (image) link is broken (only a nonsensical ALT text is displayed).

Comment: I had the same problem (and only on one Windows 10 installation and not on another) - *"A system update is required. It is not possible to install or run the program. The program requires that NuGet.Core Version 1.6.30117.9648 is first installed in GAC (Global Assembly Cache).*"

Answer (score 0):

Old one, but since I was not able to find any similar answers to how I solved there issue, here goes.

We had two identical build jobs and two almost identical deploy jobs. Build/deploy 1 was fine, build/deploy 2 failed with the error

```
Warning MSB3187: Referenced assembly '....exe' targets a different processor than the application.
```

I ended up adding build job 1 as depencdency to build job 2, still same error. They uses different nant-scripts, but the call to mage.exe was identical.

Then suddenly I found it after hours and hours. The "Artifacts paths" for the build depencency. Instead of

```
vtasclient/** => Client
DEV => Client
ICON => Client
```

I had to use

```
vtasclient/** => Client
+:DEV => Client
+:ICON => Client
```

That made the trick, why - I do not have any idea yet. Same number of files as before and all that. Kinda frustrating!!! But it solved the issue!